# How do I get the top 'realistic' hypernym from wordnet synset hyper_paths?

Tags: python, wordnet

Python3.8 nltk wordnet
How can I find the highest **reasonable** hypernym for a given word?
I'm using wordnet `synset.hypernym_paths()` which if I traverse all the way to the top gives me a hypernym that is way too abstract (ie: entity).

I've tried creating a list of 'too high' hypernyms but the list is difficult to determine and way too long.

```
import sys
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

arTooHigh = ['act', 'event', 'action', 'artifact', 'instrumentality', 'furnishing', 'organism', 'cognition', 'content', 'discipline', 'humanistic_discipline', 'diversion', 'communication', 'auditory_communication', 'speech', 'state', 'feeling', 'causal_agent', 'think', 'reason','information', 'evidence', 'measure', 'fundamental_quantity', 'condition']
arWords = ['work', 'frog', 'bad', 'corpus', 'chair', 'dancing', 'gossip', 'love', 'jerry', 'compute', 'satisfied', 'gift', 'candy', 'bookkeeper', 'construction', 'amplified', 'party', 'dinner', 'family', 'sky', 'office', 'project', 'budget', 'price']

for word in arWords:
    hypernym = word
    last = ''
    synsets = wn.synsets(word)
    syn = synsets[0]

    for path in syn.hypernym_paths():
        for i, ss in reversed(list(enumerate(path))):
            test = ss.lemmas()[0].name()        
            if test in arTooHigh:
                hypernym = last
                break
            else:
                last = test
    print(word + ' => ' + hypernym)
```

Comment: Do you have a definition of "reasonable"? Or is it like the famous un-definition of pornography: I know it when I see it? For instance, for "frog", do you expect it to stop at amphibian, vertebrate, chordate, animal, organism, living thing, whole, object, physical entity, entity. Well, "organism" is in your list, so you want it to say "animal" for "frog"?

Comment: Yea, I guess that's kind of the problem. I was hoping someone had ironed it out already. I suppose it does depend on what I'm looking for. I the case of frog, animal was what I told it to stop at. Man or woman or child would stop at person. I guess I'll have to work out that array 'arTooHigh' as best I can.
Thanks for your response.